# What is this bird of prey?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I recently took a picture of this bird flying around Geneva, Switzerland:

[image]

In the beginning, and because it was bright and the subject was against the light, I though it was simply another *Buteo buteo* as there are many around here. Now by tweaking the brightness and contrast a bit in Lightroom, I can be 99% sure that it is not a *Buteo buteo* and my mind goes more to a *Pernis apivorus*, which is another bird of prey present in the region in summertime (May-Sep).

Can anyone tell me if I am correct and what field marks can be deduced from my picture to be sure that it is the right bird?

Comment: You can also tell that is an adult male, you can tell it from the very spaced bars on the tail and wings. Beautiful light individual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice photo - Yes, I would agree with you the bands on the tail and the wings suggest that it is a Honey Buzzard *Pernis apivorus*

http://www.birdwatch.co.uk/categories/articleitem.asp?item=995
http://www.gobirding.eu/Photos/HoneyBuzzard.php

[image]
Photo by Dominic Mitchell http://www.birdingetc.com